# minidlna not indexing external usb disk drive

Tags: pi-4, usb-audio

Just installed `minidlna` on my pi 4.

I've connected an external usb disk drive containing music; which shows up at `/media/pi/Seagate Backup Plus Drive`

It also shows up with `blkid` at `/dev/vda1`:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Seagate Backup Plus Drive" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="B0581E90581E5606" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="19daeae3-01"
```

I (think) I've pointed to folder `Music` in `/etc/minidlna.conf`:

`media_dir=A,/media/pi/'Seagate Backup Plus Drive'/Music`

I run the service as root (set `user=root` in `/lib/systemd/system/minidlna.service`)

Log file appears ok:

```
minidlna.c:1126: warn: Starting MiniDLNA version 1.3.0.
minidlna.c:1186: warn: HTTP listening on port 8200
playlist.c:135: warn: Parsing playlists...
playlist.c:269: warn: Finished parsing playlists.
```

I can find the server from my devices, but - no music appears.

I had a look in the database (`/var/cache/minidlna/files.db`) - looks pretty empty.

I can browse to the music files via the pi from my LAN (using e.g. Ubuntu's 'Files' program)

I'm guessing it's something to do with how the drive is mounted maybe?